# Global estimate for weak solution of semilinear equation on unbounded area

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Suppose $u\in H^1({\mathbb{R}}^n)$ has compact support and is a weak solution of the semilinear PDE $$-\Delta u+u^3=f,\ \textrm{in}\ {\mathbb{R}}^n,$$where $f\in L^2({\mathbb{R}}^n)$. Prove that $u\in H^2({\mathbb{R}}^n)$.

(Note: Hilbert space $H^k(\Omega)=W^{k,2}(\Omega)$ is the Соболев space.)

---

By definintion, $u$ is a weak solution implies $$\int_{{\mathbb{R}}^n}-{\delta}^{ij}D_i uD_j v dx=\int_{{\mathbb{R}}^n}(-f+u^3)v dx $$holds for any $v\in H^1({\mathbb{R}}^n)$ with compact support. But the case is different since the integration takes place on ${\mathbb{R}}^n$, which is unbounded. I can not choose a cutoff function like what is done during proving the theorem for global regularity on bounded domain. I tried to take $\Omega=B_r(0)$ and letting $r\rightarrow\infty$ but the limiting process fails when I have to take an open cover of $\partial \Omega$. That seems not the right way of working out the problem.

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: But the function $u$ has compact support, right?

Comment: @Batman Yes, I know that if restricting the whole problem to a compact disc, the result holds. But the last step of the proof needs Heine-Borel Lemma of choosing finite open covering in a countable open covering, so that we can conclude that the remaining part is the union of finite open sets. So this procedure can not be kept correct during limiting.

Comment: The point @Batman is making is that if $u$ has compact support in a ball $B_r(0)$, then you can restrict the PDE to this ball and be done with it. No limiting procedure required.

Comment: The function $u^3$ a priori is not integrable for $n \ge 7$, so is it an additional assumption? Also, you can't test with $H^1$ functions unless $n \le 4$,